# Facebook: can A's friend B see posts by friend A on C's timeline when B and C are not friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I have a simple Facebook question: suppose A (for instance myself) has friends B and C, but B and C are not friends. If I post to B's timeline, then can C view such post, either in their news feed or by accessing the post by some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your privacy settings you should have the option of determining whether your posts are public or only visible to friends. If it's the latter, your newsfeed updates won't be visible to C by newsfeed. However, that doesn't override friend B's settings.

Friend B might have his or her settings set to censor or post by default all activity to his or her timeline. If you post on friend B's timeline and settings are "public", friend C (along with anyone else) would see that. If friend B reviews all timeline activity, he or she could determine whether that post is seen only by friends, friends on certain lists, or public.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, friend B can have their privacy settings set to "public", in which case friend C could see my posts to friend B's timeline, but AFAIK for this to happen friend C would at least need to know about me being friends with B, otherwise it would be unlikely that friend B will go looking for my stuff on C's timeline with all those billion+ users on Facebook. This is unless, one can write a small computer program using the Facebook API to search for all the stuff I post everywhere which is made public by C-type friends with their privacy settings set to "public". Would this be easy?